# Update reads successful in console, but the database is unaffected

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo

Trying to update a record using PHP and PDO statements.

The query fires with no errors, and the console reads the update was successful, but there is no change in the table.

So confused as to why this is happening:

```
<?php
include("../include/sessions.php");

if(isset($_POST['editcriteria']))
{
  $value = $_POST['editcriteria'];

  $editUID = $value['editUID'];
  $editAddDelete = $value['editAddDelete'];
  $editeffectiveDate = $value['editeffectiveDate'];

  try
  {
    $update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE primary_vehicle_data SET `add_delete` = :eadddelete, 
                                   `effective_date` = :eeffectivedate WHERE `uid` = :euid");

    $update->execute([
     'eadddelete' => $editAddDelete,
     'eeffectivedate' => $editeffectiveDate,
     'euid' => $editUID
    ]);

    if($update)
    {
      echo "Success: Record Updated";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Error: The Vehcile was not updated.";
    }
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}
?>
```

I simplified the above code as much as possible.  There were several more parameters, but when I removed the parameters and left it with the 3 parameters above, I still get "Success: Record Updated".  But the table is literally unaffected.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

*** UPDATE ***

I already confirmed the connection to the database is good.  I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$update` is a [`PDOStatement`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) object, so when you test

```
if ($update)
```

it will always succeed as a `PDOStatement` object is equivalent to `true`.

You should be:

1. checking the result of `$update->execute` e.g.

```
    if ($update->execute([ /* params */])) {
```

2. checking the value in [`$update->rowCount`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php), which will tell you if any rows were affected by the query.

Comment: I have never had this issue.  I do this all day, and now that I'm working on a side project, I'm having issues.  So you're saying, I need to execute the update in the IF statement, and bind the parameters in the IF statement as well?

Like this: if($update->execute(['eadddelete' => $editAddDelete,'eeffectivedate' => $editeffectiveDate])

Comment: You can just do `$result = $update->execute([ /* params */])); if ($result)` Having said that, if you have exception mode enabled most query failure modes which might return false should cause an exception. But you should definitely check `rowCount`.

Comment: So I attempted to print rowCount, and I got back 0 records were updated.  I'm so lost.  Still testing...

Comment: That probably means `$editUID` doesn't have what you think  it should in it. Either that or the row with that value has the same values as you are trying to update it to.

Comment: OMG... Bro... Thank you... I was literally stuck on this for an hour.  So much time wasted and I didn't see that the UID was not being passed into the JQuery object properly.  I... wish I could upvote your answer more than once.  Thank for being my second set of eyes.

Comment: @JohnBeasley I know just what you mean - the second set of eyes is so often all that's needed. I'm glad you got it figured out.